# Is relational model isomorphism problem GI-complete?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, computational-complexity, graph-isomorphism

I think that's true, but does anyone know of any paper on the topic?

Comment: I added the **reference-request** tag.

Comment: Additionally, a quick search via Google did not yield any results.